# How to create nested dictionary from files?

Tags: python, django, file, python-2.7, directory-structure

Let's assume, I have this structure in my fs:

```
Directory
--name.txt
--content.html
--Subdirectory
----name.txt
----content.html
------SubSubDirectory
--------name.txt
--------content.html
```

In output I would like to have:

```
content(Directory/name.txt):path(Directory/content.html)
--content(Directory/SubDirectory/name.txt):path(Directory/SubDirectory/content.html)
----content(Directory/SubDirectory/SubSubDirectory/name.txt):path(Directory/SubDirectory/SubSubDirectory/content.html)
```

I have a function:

```
def getffdirs(rootdir):
    dir = {}
    rootdir = rootdir.rstrip(os.sep)
    console.log(rootdir)
    start = rootdir.rfind(os.sep) + 1
    console.log(start)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        folders = path[start:].split(os.sep)
        shpfiles = {}
        for file in files:

            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                if readFile(os.path.join(path, file)) != '':
                    full_path = os.path.join(path, file).replace("name.txt", "index.html")
                    # shpfiles[readFile(os.path.join(path, file))] = os.path.join(path, file)
                    shpfiles[full_path] = readFile(os.path.join(path, file))
            if file.endswith(".html"):
               shpfiles['content'] = readFile(os.path.join(path, file))

        subdir = dict.fromkeys(shpfiles)
        parent = reduce(dict.get, folders[:-1], dir)
        parent[folders[-1]] = subdir
    return dir
```

which generates list of directories, subdirectories and files. I try to remodel it for my task, but I was making progress only with file nodes.

How to rebuild it for all nodes including directories and subdirectories?

Comment: What are the keys and values in the dictionary you are trying to build?

Comment: key could be a list [content(name.txt), path(content.html)] for the current folder, value - the nested dictionary for subfolders.

Comment: Or it could be a tuple, since the list is deprecated to use as a key in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
__author__ = 'pranav'

import sys
import os
from os.path import isfile
import json

try:
    myname = sys.argv[1]
except Exception, e:
    print "usage : python [listfile.py] [foldername]"
    exit(1)

def getName(myname):
    file_folder_dict = {myname: []}
    if not isfile(myname):
        try:
            for f in os.listdir(myname):
                subfolder = os.path.join(myname, f)
                file_folder_dict[myname].append(getName(subfolder))
        except:
            print "No DIR"
    else:
        return myname
    return file_folder_dict


file_folder_dict = getName(myname)

print file_folder_dict
```

I did write this script quite a while ago as a hobby. It actually gives all files and folders in dict format. This should help you.

Result:

```
{
    '/home/likewise-open/PUNESEZ/pranav.ambhore/stack_o_list_files/': [
        {
            '/home/likewise-open/PUNESEZ/pranav.ambhore/stack_o_list_files/some1': [
                '/home/likewise-open/PUNESEZ/pranav.ambhore/stack_o_list_files/some1/some1.txt',
                '/home/likewise-open/PUNESEZ/pranav.ambhore/stack_o_list_files/some1/some1.html',
                {
                    '/home/likewise-open/PUNESEZ/pranav.ambhore/stack_o_list_files/some1/some2': [
                        '/home/likewise-open/PUNESEZ/pranav.ambhore/stack_o_list_files/some1/some2/some2.html',
                        '/home/likewise-open/PUNESEZ/pranav.ambhore/stack_o_list_files/some1/some2/some2.txt'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a linear structure. I need dictionary or tuple nested one in each other in order to display it later as a nodes in browser window.

Comment: Logic is more complex here (what I struggle with): you need to go into directory and look - is there any file with .txt extension, and if yes: extract content of this file and replace name of the current directory with this content. After that move forward into subdirectories and do the same.